# Is there a way I can simplify these statements to a just a few lines of code?

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code in my android app :

```
Button selectedButton = null;
        if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_1_DAY)){
            selectedButton = mButton1;
        }else if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_5_DAYS)){
            selectedButton = mButton2;
        }else if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_30_DAYS)){
            selectedButton = mButton3;
        }else if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_3_MONTHS)){
            selectedButton = mButton4;
        }else if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_6_MONTHS)){
            selectedButton = mButton5;
        }else if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_1_YEAR)){
            selectedButton = mButton6;
        }else if(mSelectedTimePeriod.equals(ChartImageData.LAST_5_YEARS)){
            selectedButton = mButton7;
        }
        return selectedButton;
```

Is there a way I can make the mbutton1 something like mbutton[i] and LAST_1_DAY = LAST_[i]_DAY ? and put it all in a loop or something so when a subsequent button is selected, the number loads up accordingly?

Comment: `Map<String, Button>` should do it.

Comment: use switch case

Comment: @Saravana Here, `switch` would result in almost the same code, this does not simplify anything, it should rather be avoided.

Comment: @thatguy Yes correct, I didn't read question fully, thought of deleting it, will do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mapping of String and Buttons.

```
    Map<String, Button> mapping = new HashMap<String, Button>()
    mapping.put(ChartImageData.LAST_1_DAY, mbutton1);
    mapping.put(ChartImageData.LAST_5_DAYS, mbutton2);
    ....
```

And then you can do.

```
     return mapping.get(mSelectedTimePeriod);
```

This also makes it easier if you were to add an extra button in the future. All you need to do is add it to the map.

Comment: Or eliminate the loop and `if` and just use `return mapping.get(key);`

Comment: `return mapping.get(mSelectedTimePeriod);`. The point of using a `Map` is to avoid iteration and if-else-if ladder.

Comment: updated my answer to include that. you're right! thanks